# How to implement banner in website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, banner

I am C# ,ASP.net developer & I want to implement banner in website.
Can anyone help me the best way to implement banner in website

Comment: There is a Ad rotator control for this purpose. http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_adrotator.asp